# Data type mismatch in criteria expression in C# with MS Access?

Tags: c#, winforms, ms-access

Hi I try to save data's from my form to MS Access Database. There are 13 Fields to save but when i click save button error shown on this line `top.ExecuteNonQuery();` `Data type mismatch in criteria expression`.

This is my code help me as possible

```
 OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=D:/Srihari/Srihari/Invoice.accdb");
        conn.Open();

        // to save top column in invoive
        int invoicenumber = Convert.ToInt32(TXE_Invoice_Number.Text);
        string terms = CBL_Terms.Text;
        DateTime date = CBL_Date.DateTime;
        string ourquote = TXE_OurQuote.Text;
        string salesperson = CBL_Sales_Person.Text;
        string customername = CBL_Customer_Nmae.Text;
        string oderno = CBL_Order_Number.Text;
        string invoiceaddress = TXE_Invoice_Address.Text;
        string deliveryaddress = TXE_Delivery_Address.Text;

        bool inclusive = CBX_New.Checked;

        decimal Price = Convert.ToDecimal(TXE_Price.Text);
        decimal tax = Convert.ToDecimal(TXE_Tax.Text);
        decimal grandtotal = Convert.ToDecimal(TXE_Total.Text);

        OleDbCommand top = new OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO test_top(InvoiceNumber,Terms,[InvoiceDate],OurQuote,SalesPerson,CustomerName,OrderNumber,InvoiceAddress,DeliveryAddress,InclusiveStatus,Price,Tax,GrandTotal) VALUES (" + invoicenumber + ",'" + terms + "','" + date + "','" + ourquote + "','" + salesperson + "','" + customername + "','" + oderno + "','" + invoiceaddress + "','" + deliveryaddress + "','" + inclusive + "','" + Price + "','" + tax + "','" + grandtotal + "')", conn);
        top.ExecuteNonQuery();
        MessageBox.Show("Inserted Successful (top)", "Information", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
```

`conn.close();`

In Access Database 13 Columns InvoiceNumber Number, Terms Text, InvoiceDate Date/Time, OurQuote Text, SalesPerson Text, CustomerName Text, Orderno Text, InvoiceAddress Memo, DeliveryAddress Memo, InclusiveStatus Yes/No, Price Decimal, Tax Decimal, GrandTotal Decimal.

What was wrong in my code ?

Comment: Why are decimal values passed within `single Quotes` ??

Comment: Hi kyle 1st I tried like this `'"+ Price +"'` osame error came so i changed like this but still error

Comment: @SriHari - Please make yourself familiar with [parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.data.oledb.oledbparameter.aspx) and [why](http://technet.microsoft.com/library/ms161953.aspx) you should never work with a database without working with them.

Comment: #corak, Am new to C# can tel clearly ?

Comment: @SriHari - I think it is great that you're trying to learn C#. All the more reason *not* to pick up bad habits. And injecting data directly into the sql command is one of the worst habits to pick up for dealing with databases. I hope the provided links will help you to learn the "right" way to do it, so you will be spared pain and suffering down the road.

Comment: Thanks i will learn #Corak

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seriously, save yourself headaches and write more reliable code at the same time by using a parameter query:

```csharp
OleDbCommand top = new OleDbCommand(
        "INSERT INTO test_top (" +
                "InvoiceNumber,Terms,[InvoiceDate],OurQuote," +
                "SalesPerson,CustomerName,OrderNumber," +
                "InvoiceAddress,DeliveryAddress,InclusiveStatus," +
                "Price,Tax,GrandTotal" +
            ") VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)", conn);
top.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", invoicenumber);
top.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", terms);
top.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", date);
top.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", ourquote);
top.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", salesperson);
top.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", customername);
top.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", oderno);
top.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", invoiceaddress);
top.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", deliveryaddress);
top.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", inclusive);
top.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", Price);
top.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", tax);
top.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", grandtotal);
top.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Answer (score 1):

Few point's which I think you should know while saving to `Access Database`

1) `String` should be within `single Quotes`

2) `Numeric` values should **not be within Quotes**

3) `DateTime` values should be saved using **#**

Comment: Hi Kyle, If i remove Double Quote from `Numeric` and `String` Error shown like this `Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression '+ invoicenumber +'.`

Comment: I am talking about `Single Quotes`

Comment: re: "access cannot do auto conversion from text to DateTime" - Actually yes it can: `INSERT INTO Clients (LastName, DOB) VALUES ('foo', '1961-06-16')` works just fine.

Comment: @kyle see my above code I wrote like this 1st `" + invoicenumber + ",'" + terms + "'` first one is number and second one is string, you told to write string in single quotes and number not in quotes so i removed double quotes from both now my code is ` + invoicenumber + ,' + terms + '` then only error comes like that.