# "Data type mismatch in criteria expression" error in Access SQL query from C#

Tags: c#, ms-access

I am getting below Error, When I put Multiple Conditions with WHERE Clause.
Error:- Data type mismatch in criteria expression.

My Query:-

```
this.query = "UPDATE [Attendance] SET [TimeOut]='" + DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString() + "' WHERE [Emp_Id]='" + txtEmpId.Text + "'and[Date]='" + this.Date + "'";
```

Comment: Do those date fields need `#` signs? Look into using parameterized queries.  This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20242896/data-type-mismatch-in-criteria-expression-in-c-sharp-with-ms-access

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Access SQL tends to be rather flexible when accepting Date/Time values as strings. However, since you **really should** be using a parameterized query anyway because

- they're safer (by avoiding SQL Injection issues),
- you don't have to mess with delimiters for date and text values,
- you don't have to worry about escaping quotes within text values, and
- they handle dates properly so your code doesn't mangle dates on machines set to `dd-mm-yyyy` format,

consider using the following approach

```csharp
this.query = "UPDATE [Attendance] SET [TimeOut]=? WHERE [Emp_Id]=? AND [Date]=?";
cmd.CommandText = this.query;
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", DateTime.Now.ToString("H:mm:ss"));
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", txtEmpId.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", this.Date);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```